# How can I open text file and display it in a richtext area

Tags: c#

When run the following it displays something looking like some sort of encoding problem (symbols and such).  The file was made and save from notepad with the default encoding.  Tried changing encoding no help.

Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void spider(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string myText = File.ReadAllText("watchlist.txt");
        richTextBox1.Text = myText;

    }
}
```

Comment: encoding issue or reading issue? becase this code is running well.

Comment: your code works fine, so the error must lie somewhere you haven't shown us, what are the contents of the file (specifically does it contain none English characters), the location, and the default encoding?

Comment: the method File.ReadAllText attempt to read a file with UTF8 encoding, How do save your file, in which encoding.

Comment: on a general note, if you are only loading text you might as well use a normal text box, RT is only needed if you want to display formatting using the RTF standard, though the box only supports a limited subset

Comment: created a whole new file using textpad with nothing but "hello world" and got same problem.  then tried saving specifing UTF8 and same thing.  tried all encodes same thing.  tried notepad same thing. .... i'm bumin .... thanks for the help though

Comment: ok i think i'm onto something:  i removed all the readfile stuff and simply assigned myText = "THIS IS A TEST STRING"; and it displayed that with the same encoding problem .... so the issue is not the reading of file or its encoding but rather the display of the string in the richtextbox!

Answer (score 0):

You could use StreamReader with the using syntax

```
try
{
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("filename"))
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    // some exception processing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

second parameter could be encoding. you can select any encoding what you need.

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("fullpath.txt", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, false))
{
    richTextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  problem was not with encoding of the file, but rather the font of the textarea display....i did not have the font that the display property was set to so anything looked like symbol garbege that i printed in that area.  Simply changed the properties of the textarea to ariel and worked fine.

Thanks for the help all.